# How to load efficiently a big matrix (20k x 20k) from a txt file of ~3-4 GB into Rstudio? [Subgraph extraction]

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, correlation

I have 3 big matrices dataset containing correlation data from a dataset i'm working on that represent 3 different network.

Matrices are like this: [Matrix_sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LwD2.png)

It's 19370 x 19370 which has values separated by tabulation ("\t").
Because it's a correlation matrix, the only good values (and the ones i'm interested in) are on the upper diagonal matrix, so only the values that are not NA.
NA on the upper diagonal matrix are to be considered like no correlation.

I tried the following algorithm:

```
processFile <- function(filepath)
{
  rows <- vector()
  cols <- vector()
  values <- vector()
  counter <- 1
  while (TRUE)
    {
      start_time <- Sys.time()
      line <- read_lines(filepath,skip=counter,n_max=1)
      if ( length(line) == 0 )
      {
        break
      }
      
      line <- strsplit(line,split="\t",fixed=T)
      for(i in counter+2:length(line[[1]]))
      {
        if(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(line[[1]][i]))))
        {
          rows <- append(rows,counter+1)
          cols <- append(cols,i-1)
          values <- append(values,as.numeric(line[[1]][i]))
        }
      }
      end_time <- Sys.time()
      diff <- end_time-start_time
      print(paste("Progress: ",round(counter/19369*100,2),"%"))
      print(paste("Line: ", counter))
      print(diff)
      counter <- counter+1
  }
  #M <- list(rows,cols,values)
  M <- sparseMatrix(i=rows,j=cols,x=values,dims=c(counter-1,counter-1))
  return(M)
}
```

Explation of the algorithm:

- As you can see what i do is a cycle that read line per line the matrix and stop when there are no lines to read.
- It split the single line by tabulation and, in a for cycle starting from the good values, add that values to a vector and save into other vectors internal positions of these values in the matrix (i need them to create the sparse matrix).
- The start_time, end_time and others are just for getting an idea of how much time it's taking for a single line.

Further comments:

- A weird thing i noticed is that the time difference between each line increases each time a new line is processed. It's weird cause every time it process a new line the starting point is shifted to right of 1 position, so the time should be less and less since i process the matrix diagonally. I can't explain why it happens.
- I tried the algorithm with a test matrix that is way less big than that and it works perfectly but with big data is another story, it takes too much time (it start with 2s per line and increase to 30s per line at line 7 or 8).
  I found that the critical part is obviously the for cycle and it take the most time compared to the other operations.

I'm relatively new to R and considering that i wanna extract a subnet from it (that is a submatching graph problem) i don't know how to handle this big data efficiently in rstudio.

Keeping in mind that i'm working with nets (igraph package of R) should i proceed to import it like that or work directly on the txt file with the big matrices? Is there another efficent way to do the subgraph extraction?

Hope you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Are you memory limited? If not, use `data.table::fread` to import all data at once. All these `read_lines`, `strsplit` and `append` are inherently slow.

Comment: Wow i tried before fread but it hadn't work, i don't remember why. Now i gave it another try and it read it in less than 10s. Thank you so much! Is it possible to convert it to matrix or even better sparse matrix? I wanna use it as an adjacency matrix.
ps. i have 16gb ram

Comment: Converting to a matrix might be a bit slow and need too much memory but try `as.matrix`. You could develop something clever to transform to a sparse matrix yourself or look around for solutions. [This](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mltools/versions/0.3.5/topics/sparsify) might be useful (but I haven't tested it).